Dropping messages on ethernet via UDP on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
I am currently working with a LiDAR sensor and connecting it to my Dell Precision 5560 PC running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. It has only USB C ports hence I am using a Dell USB C to RJ45 adapter for ethernet connection to LiDAR. The problem is that I am dropping messages on UDP when I try to look at the pointcloud provided by the sensor. The pointcloud is basically a 3D array of points with other info like intensity etc. I can see some scan lines consistently dropping messages on the pointcloud visualizer and I also get a dropped messages warning. None of the other Ubuntu PCs I have tested with have this problem. Does anyone know what might be the issue? Has anyone faced a similar issue?
